# How can I get onKeyPress to give me the last key input with a Braille Display on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, accessibility

I deleted the previous version of this question because it was all over the place. Sorry about that. I am using React Native. The issue I am having is that when using a Braille Display (Orbit Reader 20) to input letters into a `TextInput` field on iOS I get a concatenated string of all the character and not the last one I entered. I have tried this on Android as well, but on Android, it works the way I want it to. iOS will behave like Android, but only if I have focus on the onscreen keyboard and not on the actual input field.

**Descriptions of the problem** (all letters are typed with a braille display): I have focus on the input area, I type in the letter 'b'. In the input area, the letter 'b' appears which is what I want to happen. Next, I type in the letter 'c' which on Android will give me just the letter 'c', but on iOS I get the string "bc" which I get the key using `keyPress.nativeEvent.key`. It seems like iOS is not respecting the `maxLength` prop when input comes from the braille device.

**What I have tried**: I have tried to just cut the last letter off of the key by using `keyPress.nativeEvent.key.slice(-1)` which does give the single letter, but it messes with VoiceOver and TalkBack (example: 'a' is displayed in the text area then I type 'b' and the phone says "ab"). I have found that if I clear the input area using `textInput.current.clear()` when `onChangeText` is triggered it will give me the results I want in that `keyPress.nativeEvent.key` will give me the last letter, but it will clear out my text immediately and cuts off VoiceOver.

**Code Snippet** (this is the code for my custom TextInput component and just has some console.log statements so that I can see what is going on.):

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';


const BrailleInput = props => {
    const textInput = useRef();
    const [valueLetter, setValueLetter] = useState('');

    const handleInput = input => {
        console.log("onChangeText: " + input);
    };

    const handleClear = keyPress => {
        setValueLetter(keyPress.nativeEvent.key);

        console.log("onKeyPress: " + keyPress.nativeEvent.key);
    };


    return (
        <View style={props.style}>
            <TextInput
                ref={textInput}
                style={styles.textInput}
                maxLength={1}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoFocus={true}
                onKeyPress={handleClear}
                onChangeText={handleInput}
                value={valueLetter}
                caretHidden={true}
            />
        </View>
    );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textInput: {
        height: '50%',
        width: '100%',
        borderColor: '#ffec33',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 4,
        color: '#ffec33',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 40
    },
});


export default BrailleInput;
```

**Output:** 
iOS:

```
onKeyPress: a
onChangeText: a
onKeyPress: Backspace
onChangeText: 
onKeyPress: ab
onChangeText: a
```

Android:

```
onKeyPress: a
onChangeText: a
onKeyPress: b
onKeyPress: c
```

I want the iOS output to look more like the Android Output. For some reason, it gives me extra `Backspace` inputs for the iOS version which I think are the main reason VoiceOver is not working like I want.

In the end, all I want is to have accessibility focus on the `TextInput` area, have TalkBack/VoiceOver speak the single letter that I input then be able to type another letter in to replace the previous letter, rinse, repeat. I need an accessible solution to this I have already been able to make a non-accessible solution.

Comment: FYI: `keypress` is deprecated and doesn't trigger for non-printable characters. Use `keydown` instead.

Comment: The `onKeyPress` prop on `TextInput` has been deprecated and replaced by `onKeyDown`? Is that right? I'm using React Native.

Comment: The `keypress` event itself has been deprecated. Accessing it with `onkeypress` is still valid, but the event itself is no longer supported, so you should move over to `onkeydown` to bind to the `keydown` event instead of the `keypress` event.

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying. `keyPress` as used in my code snippet is just a variable name. Also in this instance, I don't care if it doesn't trigger for non-printable characters because I only want to display A-Z.

Comment: My mistake then. When I see onkeypress in any code that relates to JavaScript, I assume (as would anyone else I believe) that you are working with the `keypress` event. I just wanted to let you know that that event is deprecated. That's all.

Comment: what is `setValueLetter`? Is this some custom function as I can't find any reference to it (sadly not a react user so I always have to refer to docs).

Comment: `setValueLetter` is a custom function.

Comment: can you show us what that function does? I would suspect that something isn't quite right there.

Comment: Which function are you referring to @GrahamRitchie? This could be boiled down to one function which simply clears out the text in the `TextInput` and replaces it with the new letter that is entered from the Braille Display.