# How can I update an accessibility label programmatically in React Native?

Tags: react-native, accessibility, react-native-ios, voiceover

I am new to React Native and cross-platform programming so please bear with me. I will try to lay this out as logically as possible.

**What I am trying to do:** I have a custom component called TextDisplay that looks like this

```js
const TextDisplay = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <View 
        style={props.style}>
            <Text
            style={styles.textStyle}
            ref={ref}
            accessibilityLabel={props.label}>
                {props.children}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
});
```

Basically I have a single letter displayed in this `Text` component which I need to have accessibility focus at all times. The user types in a letter and the letter typed will then be displayed in the `TextDisplay` component. The code that does that looks like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, AccessibilityInfo, findNodeHandle, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import TextDisplay from './TextDisplay';

const PortraitKeyboard = props => {

 const textDisplay = React.createRef();
 const [value, setValue] = useState('');

 const handleKeyPressDelay = (keyPress) => {
        let inputLength = keyPress.nativeEvent.key.length;

        if (inputLength == 1) {
            const letter = keyPress.nativeEvent.key.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').toLowerCase();
            setValue(letter);
            textDisplay.current.focus();
            const reactTag = findNodeHandle(textDisplay.current);
            AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
        }
 };

 return (

            <TextDisplay
                style={styles.textInput}
                ref={textDisplay}
                label={value}>
                {value}
            </TextDisplay>

            <TextInput
                onKeyPress={handleKeyPressDelay}
            />
 );

};
```

This works just like I want it to on Android devices.

**The Problem:**  Let me preface this by saying this problem only exists on iOS devices. When the newly input letter is changed in the `TextDisplay` component it does not immediately (sometimes never) change the accessibility label for the `TextDisplay` component. For example, the `TextDisplay` component is empty and I type in the letter 'a' which works fine, but when I type in 'b' which replaces the 'a' that was previously typed it will continue to say 'a' and not say 'b' with VoiceOver. If I swipe up to the same component it just constantly says the wrong letter. Only when I switch focus to another component and come back does it say the correct letter, or if I double tap on the component it will also be correct. For the purposes of this app, I need the letter displayed to be spoken without any additional interaction from the user.

**What I've tried:**  I have tried googling this problem and how to refresh the accessibility label, but it is such a specific issue and it deals with accessibility I find nothing. I have tried to change the accessibility label manually with [Direct Manipulation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation) but it doesn't seem to work for VoiceOver to repeat the letter. I've also tried moving the accessibility focus from one component to the next which does work but the results are A: slow (for some reason it takes about 2 seconds for accessibility focus to move which I would need to do twice.) and B: it will speak whatever component I swap to then speak what I want.

All I need is a way to force iOS to refresh the accessibility label for the component when I change the letter inside. Is there some way to fake a touch so that I can select the item? Or is there some easier solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it's causing the error, but why are you using different props that are referencing the same value? why not to use the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to do with another accessibility issue I'm having on iOS regarding `TextInput` and input from a braille display. I posted that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582404/how-can-i-get-onkeypress-to-give-me-the-last-key-input-with-a-braille-display-on) too but it never got answered. It works around that issue but then I hit this problem.